# Why Symfony2 DateTime returns a day earlier?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, sonata-admin

My code in `controller`:

```
  $yesterday = new \DateTime();
  $yesterday->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
  $customerReportForm->add('dateFrom', 'date', ['data'=> $yesterday 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker',  "data-date-format"=>"yy-mm-dd")]);
  $customerReportForm->add('dateTo', 'date', ['data'=>$yesterday,' 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker',  "data-date-format"=>"yy-mm-dd")]);
```

And I have POST handler in same controller method:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST'))
{
  $dateFrom = $customerReportForm->get('dateFrom')->getData();
  $dateTo = $customerReportForm->get('dateTo')->getData();
}
```

values of `dateFrom` and `dateTo` shows me date a day earlier then I'm select in form.

For example, if I'm will type in datepicker "2015-30-12" it will show me "2015-29-12"

Why?

Just `var_dump(new DateTime())` shows correct date.

PHP 5.5.29
Symfony - 2.3

Comment: I don't understand the issue here as well... Can you clarify a bit? Setting the `data` attribute is counter-productive. Please update your question with controller/form code...

Comment: ^^ It sounds like you aren't handling the request that comes in.  You should be type hinting your controller action with `Request $request` instead of having to use `$this->getRequest()`, and you also need a call to `$customerReportForm->handleRequest($request)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is your real problem...
You use `$yesterday->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));`. It's normally behaviour that your date is earlier than today.

You use a sub function php on the new DateTime.

Comment: No, it's default value in form. I change it in datepicker and submit